# How To Fetch Data From API With This Format In Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

Endpoint - https://data.geoiq.io/dataapis/v1.0/covid/locationcheck

{
"key": string,
"latlngs": array
}

[enter image description here][1]

How To Fetch Data From API With This Format In Flutter
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6hVH.png

Comment: Take a look here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

Basically your API endpoint is asking for body.
In flutter, you can use package **http: ^0.12.1**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final api = 'https://data.geoiq.io/dataapis/v1.0/covid/locationcheck';
final response = http.post(api, body: { "key": string, "latlngs": array });
```

And if API endpoint requires an Authentication token. For example Bearer token then you can use

```
final token = 'YOUR TOKEN';

final response = http.post(api, body: { "key": string, "latlngs": array }, headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find below a sample request.

```
import json as js
import requests
body =    {"latlngs": [
            [
                12.967444,
                77.498775

            ],
            [
                14.656773,
                77.627936
            ],
            [
                19.200027,
                72.970519
            ],
            [
                12.962882,
                77.543543
            ]],
        "key": "Auth Key"} 
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url = "https://data.geoiq.io/dataapis/v1.0/covid/locationcheck", data = js.dumps(body), headers = headers)
```